# MySql Connector 6.5.4 - Stored Procedure Return Entity with a boolean field - Entity Framework

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, stored-procedures

Searching, reading forums and all suggestion of SO before writing. (1 day already investigating the issue).

Im using: MySql Server 5.5 with Entity Framework 4.3 with Connector 6.5.4
(I was using connector 6.3.6 and everything worked perfectly, updated and problem occurs)

I have a SP that returns an List of an Entity Object. That Entity have a bool (tinyint(1)) field BUT when using the SP it returns it as string.

I created a temporary table and return that but the same problems occurs. The error is:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The 'isDeleted' property on 'Container' could not be   
set to a 'String' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 
'Boolean'. at 
System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.
GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
```

Problem is, since it's a Entity object, i cannot Convert.ToBoolean() [also i dont want to].
I think the problem is that i don't have the ability to cast the SP field as bool or the connector has a bug (most likely).

As I said, it worked with no problem with connector 6.3.6

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is there but I found a workaround. The problem happend when the order of the fields aren't the same.

This BUG: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=53166 helped me to understand and try making the select order of fileds the same the table.

Example:
If table is :

field_a, field_b, field_c

and your stored procedures returns: field_b, field_a, field_c won't work.

Changed my SP to return field_a, field_b, field_c